# Does Jyotisha shastra use factors besides the horoscope to make predictions of the future?

Tags: astrology

Recently somebody posted that the astrological chart based on birth place and time applies with different efficacy to different castes.

What are all the factors traditional astrologers would use for predictions?

Comment: Astrological charts are analysed in same way  for all Castes, even non-hindus life can be predicted well.. but many Astrologers learn thumb rules and might interpret differently different castes, but someone with good philosophical understanding doesn't need to see caste or religion of native.

Answer (score 0):

In palmistry natal charts (horoscopes) are not needed. By seeing palm lines an astrologer can predict future of the native. It is particularly useful when native's date of birth or time of birth are not known.

By studying various physical traits of human beings predictions can be made about the future too. This falls under palmistry, Samudrika Shastra.

Quoting from an abridged version of the [Garuda Purana](https://www.astrojyoti.com/garudapurana-4.htm):

> PREDICTIONS BASED ON PHYSICAL TRAITS
>
> Dwelling on length about the importance of physical traits and
> symptoms apparent in an individual, Lord Vishnu told Shiva-‘ If one
> sees the following physical traits in a man, he should immediately
> understand that he is seeing a prospective King : Hands and feet as
> soft as a Lotus flower, pink nails and no space left between the
> fingers when kept straight. There is no sign of bulging veins on his
> hands and palms and they do not sweat excessively. On the contrary, a
> person having rough feet that appears pale, with prominent veins on
> them indicates that the concerned person would be poor and miserable.’
>
> PREDICTING AGE WITH THE HELP OF FOREHEAD LINE
>
> Lord Vishnu said-‘ Anybody having three parallel lines on his forehead
> lives happily for sixty years whereas two parallel lines indicates
> that he would live till the age of forty years. Only one line on the
> forehead indicates that he would have a short life but if the line
> stretches up to both the ears then he lives for a century. If two
> parallel lines on the forehead stretches up to both the years then the
> concerned person lives for seventy years while a triple parallel lines
> reaching both the years indicates that he would live till the age of
> sixty years. A forehead devoid of any line on it means that the
> concerned person would live for only forty years while a cobweb of
> intersecting lines on the forehead indicates that the concerned person
> is definite to die a premature death. A forehead with a Trident or an
> Axe mark on it indicates that the concerned person would be prosperous
> and live for a century.
>
> PREDICTING AGE BY PALMISTRY
>
> Lord Vishnu, continuing with his narration told Shiva that the age of
> a person could be predicted by the lines found on his palms- ‘ If the
> life line reaches the base between index and middle fingers then the
> concerned person lives for a century. If the life line is long, clear
> and without intersections from other lines then the concerned person
> lives for a hundred years.
>
> PREDICTION BASED ON PHYSICAL TRAITS OF WOMEN
>
> Lord Vishnu said-‘A woman having a round face, curly hair and lower
> portion of her navel slightly slanted towards right, is extremely
> fortunate not only for herself but also for her whole clan. Similarly,
> a woman with golden complexion and hands as beautiful and soft as red
> lotus flower is exceptionally chaste and faithful towards her husband.
> A woman having dry and unruly hair and also round eyes becomes a
> widow.
>
> A woman whose face is round like a full moon and which radiates like a
> rising Sun and whose lips are juicy like a ‘Bael’ fruit (Wood apple),
> enjoys a happy and contented life. A woman having a cobweb of lines on
> her palms is sure to lead a torturous and painful life whereas a palm
> with few lines indicates that she would be poor. If the lines are
> pink, then they indicate happiness, prosperity and good health whereas
> blackish lines indicate that she would live a life of slavery. Any
> woman having either a ‘Chakra’, a hook or a ear ring mark on her hand
> indicates that she would beget worthy sons and rule like a queen. A
> woman having hair around her breasts as well as a protruding lower lip
> spells doom for her husband. Any woman having a festoon mark on her
> palms indicates that she would get married in a family superior to her
> in status.
>
> A woman having a round navel with brown hair around it leads a life of
> slavery despite being born in a royal family. A woman whose little
> toes as well as big toes of both the legs do not touch the ground
> while walking spells doom for her husband. In the same manner
> beautiful eyes indicate good fortune while soft and tender skin
> indicate a happy married life.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go through all the factors here. But, the answer to your first question/confusion is much simpler than you think.

The natal chart is the reflection of all the karmas the person has done, due to which they have chose to be born in a certain time that fits with the results of their karma that they will get. However, this is only a record of all the major karmas TILL birth. After your birth, you can do karmas do Parihaara for certain things to not get their results or postpone those results via use of gemstones and so on. Moreover, the karma you do in your current life can alter or shift the karma you are destined to get.

Of course, you cannot really change the karma of, say your wife dying early. But, what you can do is Tapasyaa, to be detached from your emotions for example. Then, when a turbulent time comes for the Moon, because of your current life karma, maybe you're not as badly affected as you would have been if your karmas would have been the same as the time you were born.

In this way, the efficacy of the certainty of the astrological prediction has gone down. Perhaps you were meant to go crazy or commit suicide, but because of your karma, now you didn't.

For Shudras (which is well over 90% of people), who haven't done Upanayana, do not have knowledge of Shashtras or the Veda, do not participate in any Yajnas to reduce karmic effect like the Pavamana Suktam related Yajnas and so on... neither do they do any tapasya or sadhana, well at-least they're not expected to do so... Probably no Parihaara either, if they even believe in jyotisha in the first place, even which is doubtful.

It's clear due to all these reasons and more that Shudras are most likely to be closer to 100% certainty via the natal and other divisional charts than other Varnas.

Similarly, the opposite is true for Brahmanas, and their astrological charts is the least effective.

But obviously, to apply this, you don't look at a person's surname or anything of that sort, but rather his knowledge, gati, profession, sadhana and nature. And, the most important factor is relation to the Veda, and particularly Yajnas. Yajnas can reduce bad karma, they can create a HUGE amount of good karma to the point where 100 Ashvamedha Yajnas can produce the Karma to fit the position of Indra in Svarga, for example.

For anyone associated with Yajnas, their astrological chart is a gentle suggestion rather than a certainty because their small, voluntary, free-willed current life karmas (to do yajna), have the ability to produce huge karma that alters future lives as well as current life (for example, you can get sons from certain yajnas, or wives, or money, etc, in current life).

Here's an example. Let's pick Elon Musk, he is a Shudra, he has no relation to veda or Yajnas neither to any prayer or anything else of the sort. In his natal chart, you will be able to see he will make a LOT of money and he will get very famous. And that's what will happen, with 95-100% certainty. In-fact, just the fact that a conman like him has reached such heights is almost entirely due to his good karma regarding money and fame from past lives.

Now, let's take a religious vaishya who is well associated with the Veda, and let's assume his janma chart shows he will earn barely enough to live.

Now, there's various Lakshmi mantras, Yajnas etc to get wealth, which he does. His Tapasya for this is a lot. Now, when you look at his chart, despite it suggesting that he will barely get by monetarily in the Hora chart D-2, in fact, due to all of this, he will make plenty of money to live comfortably at-least, even if he doesn't get rich.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Astrology is different from Jyothisha. Astrology is just Nakshatra palan which does not vary for persons grouped under a star.

Jyothisha is a study of human behaviour and ways to improve self conduct.
Jyothisha is considered important few years before Hindu marriages.
But astrology comes life long. Mixing or generalising all concepts is wrong.

Example
Can a Chinese having different blood cell composition donate blood to Indian blood bank association?  Or can a father donate blood to daughter without checking blood group?
Above is similar to Jyothisha & Astrology

Comment: You should add scriptural sources.